# IF with && and || condition SalesForce Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, conditional

I have a trigger that checks the stage of an OPP before it updates.

What I want to do is check if the new Stage is 'X' then the Old Stage is not 'Y' or 'Z' there could be 4 more stages, so if a new stage is this and older stages is not one of the 'a, B, C' then go in and throw an Error. Please see the code below for example.

```
trigger StageCheck on Opportunity (before update) {

    for(Opportunity OPP : Trigger.new)
        
    {
    string OldStage  = trigger.old[0].Stage;
    string NewStage  = trigger.new[0].Stage;
        
    if(OldStatus == 'A' && NewStatus != 'B')
    {
        OPP.addError('Status can only move to B');
        return;
    }
     else if(OldStatus == 'B' && NewStatus != 'C' || NewStatus != 'A' )
        {
        OPP.addError('Status can only move to Stage A or C');
        return;
        }
 
    }
}
```

Currently, it keeps firing even when my new stage is A or C. What am I doing wrong?
Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you just using the same stage skipping logic as recommended in your other posts?

Comment: That's only working in the Validation rule, we have much more complicated scenarios, Stage 1 can be skipped to 10, to accommodate the complication we need more custom solutions like check more than one combination of stages.  For example, if I were to use that method that simply takes one number and minus the older stage then when skipping from stage 1 - 10  = -9 that will keep firing we need to make exceptions. That's why I chose Trigger because it's a little more customizable.

Comment: the above doesn't compile - OldStatus v OldStage; use [edit] to fix

Comment: You should also be consistent in your examples. You're using X, Y, and Z in your text but A, B, and C in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a high level this is an issue of one of the basics of programming, operator precedence.

Given the following expression
`X && Y || Z`

It could be evaluated two ways.

- You can evaluate `X && Y` first, then use the result in the final operation `<IntermediateResult> || Z`
- You can evaluate `Y || Z` first, then use the result in the first operation `X && <IntermediateResult>`

When there is more than one syntactically valid way to evaluate an expression, it's said to be *ambiguous*. It's important that one possible evaluation is chosen, and that it's chosen *consistently*.

The rules to determine how to evaluate expressions are fairly common, and much like math. Evaluation happens from left to right, and follows the [Operator Precedence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_precedence.htm) for Apex.

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so your expression is evaluated as `(X && Y) || Z`.

#### Another thing

There's also *short-circuit evaluation* to keep in mind. If you have `TRUE || <something>`, it doesn't matter what the result of `<something>` is because if *any* part of an OR expression is true, the entire thing is true. We (well, Salesforce) can skip evaluating the entirety of `<something>`. Why waste time calculating something that won't effect the end result?

Same thing with `FALSE && <something>`. If any part in an AND expression is FALSE, the result is guaranteed to be FALSE.

#### Putting it together

I have to make the assumption that the thing you're having trouble with is the `else if(OldStatus == 'B' && NewStatus != 'C' || NewStatus != 'A' )` in your example (your question isn't clear enough to know that this is indeed the issue).

If that's the case, then the fix is to use parenthesis to make your expression less ambiguous (again, much like in math).

`else if(OldStatus == 'B' && (NewStatus != 'C' || NewStatus != 'A'))`
would ensure that the `NewStatus` parts are evaluated before AND-ing with `OldStatus == 'B'`.

Comment: I selected this answer to be the best one, I selected the approach where I would check each status one by one or A vs B instead of A vs B and C. It made it possible, its a little more code but it worked! Thanks Derek F

Answer (score 6):

Derek F's post has it most of the context around this issue, but I just wanted to add one more thing.

An evaluation of `(NewStatus != 'C' || NewStatus != 'A')` will always result in TRUE.

The evaluation is either it is NOT C OR NOT A. Each of those conditions is evaluated on their own.

Let use the example where `NewStatus = 'C'`,

First, it looks at the first part: is NewStatus not 'C'? No, that part is false.

Then evaluate the next part, is it not 'A', Yes. Therefore the whole condition evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: this is correct, now it's making everything true regardless of condition A!

Comment: When it is != you usually want AND not OR

Answer (score 6):

What you need is a "valid map" to determine which stages can be gotten to from which other stage. You don't need any complicated if statements with such a setup.

Here's a hard-coded example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> validChanges = new Map<String, List<String>> {
  'A' => new String[] { 'B' },
  'B' => new String[] { 'A', 'C' },
  // ... more mappings ... //
};
```

Once you have this all mapped out, you can reduce your main logic to just:

```
for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.size; i < s; i++) {
  String oldStatus = Trigger.old[i].StageName, newStatus = Trigger.new[i].StageName;
  String[] validStatusChanges = validChanges.get(oldStatus);
  if(oldStatus != newStatus && !validStatusChanges.contains(newStatus)) {
    Trigger.new[i].StageName.addError(
    'You cannot move from '+oldStatus+' to '+newStatus+
    '. Valid changes are: '+String.join(validStatusChanges,', '));
  }
}
```

*(Note, you could write it other ways, I just find this seems to read pretty easy).*

Even better, this allows you to specifically tell the user which valid changes they may make.

If you wanted to make this not hard-coded, you could use a [Custom Metadata](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_overview#:%7E:text=A%20custom%20metadata%20type%20is,are%20also%20metadata%2C%20not%20data.) object to store the valid mappings, and decode that during runtime.

```
Map<String, List<String>> validChanges = new Map<String, List<String>>();
for(StageChange__mdt change: StageChange__mdt.getAll().values()) {
  String[] stageChanges = validChanges.get(change.OldStage__c);
  if(stageChanges == null) {
    validChanges.put(change.OldStage__c, stageChanges = new String[0]);
  }
  stageChanges.add(change.NewStage__c);
}
```

This requires a bit more setup, but allows you to change the legal steps without updating any code at all.

Sometimes, the best solution to a problem isn't to try and attack it head-on, but to find an easier method. Hard-coding a list of values in a huge if-else chain is just asking for trouble. Not only do you have to deal with maintaining code, but code coverage for a head-on attack would be challenging compared to more dynamic methods.